# How to parse xml in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, xml

I am working with the xml below is xml

```
<message xml="Local:client" type="message" to="123456@Local" from="147852369/a02c9bb1"><GET xml="http://Local.org/protocol/message"></GET></message>
```

Now **how to get the value of "to"?**.I tried with below code. But it is showing null value

```
[message elementForName:@"to" xml:@"Local:client"];
```

Please any body help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message` is an element and `to` is attribute of message element ...

To get `to` from message use

```
[message attributeForName:@"to"]
```

Comment: HI if you don't mind can you please check the this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048565/how-to-parse-a-xmpp-xml-in-ios]

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser,
    didStartElement elementName: String,
    namespaceURI: String?,
    qualifiedName: String?,
    attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]){

        println("attributess name is \([attributeDict])")

        if elementName=="message" {
            let attrs = attributeDict
            if let prop = attrs["to"] {

                println("property 'to'=\(prop)")
            }

        }

}
```