# How to parse a xmpp xml in ios?

Tags: ios, xml, xmppframework, nsxml

Hi I am working with the xmpp every thing working fine.But I am unable to parse  below xml

```
<message
xmlns="jabber:client" to="919452544@server" id="859e7-870" type="chat" from="917696997127@server/Smack">
<body>Broadcast</body>
<properties
    xmlns="http://www.jivesoftware.com/xmlns/xmpp/properties">
    <property>
        <name>stream</name>
        <value type="string">8d879bea44f792468d6ecad161d3e545</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>date</name>
        <value type="string">2016-05-05 10:36:25</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>broadcast</name>
        <value type="string">Broadcast</value>
    </property>
</properties>
</message>
```

in the above xml first i need to check that body is equal to Broadcast.
Then i need to parse `<name>stream</name><value type="string">8d879bea44f792468d6ecad161d3e545</value>`
How to get the name and value in above xml.
I tried like this but every time condition is success.below is my code

```
 if ([message elementsForName:@"name"] ) {
    NSArray *nameArray=[message elementsForName:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"name Broadcast  %@",nameArray);

}
```

but nameArray always empty.please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...  `<name>stream</name>` is array element and `<property>... <\property>` is NSArray

```
NSXMLElement *properties = [message elementForName:@"properties"];
NSArray *property = [properties elementsForName:@"property"];
NSLog(@"property: %@", property);

//loop to get name and value
for (NSXMLElement *i in property)
{
    NSXMLElement *name = [i elementForName:@"name"];
    NSString *n = [name stringValue];
    NSLog(@"name: %@", n);
    // like wise you can get value
}
```